# Get latest records in last month using date_format in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

Hi I have a querywhich is

```
SELECT money,x.user_id as data_user_id,client,x.created_on FROM `user_data` x  LEFT join `users` as `u` ON `u`.`id` = `x`.`user_id` WHERE `x`.`user_id` = 3 AND  date(x.created_on) <= concat(DATE_FORMAT( NOW() , '%Y-%m'),'-02'  ) order by x.created_on
```

And I am getting following results

```
money    data_user_id   client     created_on
----------------------------------------------
 1000       3             navy         2016-12-04 
 2000       3             navy         2016-12-02
 3000       3             vast         2016-12-03
```

But i need only two records like

```
money    data_user_id   client     created_on
----------------------------------------------
1000       3             navy         2016-12-04
3000       3             vast         2016-12-03
```

Could any one help me to resolve the issue???

Comment: add a GROUP BY client

Comment: What is the criteria to choose `2016-12-04` record instead of `2016-12-02`?

Comment: I want to get only latest record based on created_on which is equal to or less than of 02nd of every month

Comment: if i do a group_by i am getting 2016-12-02 record not 2016-12-04 record

Comment: is there any field of table `users` in select statement? because there isn't any u.field in the sentence.

Comment: yeah actually money is from users table only

Comment: you should add table schemas